# How to find nearest day of week in php?

Tags: php, date, dayofweek, weekday

How to find a speciefic nearest day of the week in PHP if initially I have a date string like: `07.05.2010`? For example, I want to find the nearest Sunday (or any day of the week). How can I implement this? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm? If so, can you specify the required input/output?

Comment: You might find this solution interesting: http://is.gd/bXrha

Comment: @nuqqsa Zend_Date is just a pain to use imho

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do:

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime('07.05.2010')));
```

Comment: Not if the latter is a german date format MM.DD.YYYY - strtotime will screw that up. You'll have to find a solution for that as well to get my upvote :)

Comment: Plus, be sure to test out the edge cases. What happens if 07.05.2010 itself is a sunday?

Comment: "next Sunday" is not necessarily the "nearest Sunday"

Comment: ask your users to inpt the date in the proper format .. otherwise u cant find out if its  05/07 or 07/05 that the user entered

Comment: Thanks, it worked even if the date is a Sunday too. Shame on me of not knowing this 'next %dayofweek%' method for 'strtotime'...

Comment: So by *nearest* you actually meant *next* ?

Answer (score 17):

Just in case you wanted the *nearest* day rather than the *next* one, here is a way to do that.

```
$target = "Sunday";
$date   = "07.05.2010";

// Old-school DateTime::createFromFormat
list($dom, $mon, $year) = sscanf($date, "%02d.%02d.%04d");
$date = new DateTime("$year/$mon/$dom -4 days");
// Skip ahead to $target day
$date->modify("next $target");

echo $date->format("d.m.Y");
```

And as of PHP 5.3, that middle portion can be simply

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("!d.m.Y", $date)
        ->modify("-4 days")->modify("next $target");
```

Comment: geez, I was overcomplicating things. Nice +1

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @param $dayOfWeek - e.g Monday, Tuesday ...
 */
public function findNearestDayOfWeek(\DateTime $date, $dayOfWeek)
{
    $dayOfWeek = ucfirst($dayOfWeek);
    $daysOfWeek = array(
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
        'Sunday',
    );
    if(!in_array($dayOfWeek, $daysOfWeek)){

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid day of week:'.$dayOfWeek);
    }
    if($date->format('l') == $dayOfWeek){

        return $date;
    }

    $previous = clone $date;
    $previous->modify('last '.$dayOfWeek);

    $next = clone $date;
    $next->modify('next '.$dayOfWeek);

    $previousDiff = $date->diff($previous);
    $nextDiff = $date->diff($next);

    $previousDiffDays = $previousDiff->format('%a');
    $nextDiffDays = $nextDiff->format('%a');

    if($previousDiffDays < $nextDiffDays){

        return $previous;
    }

    return $next;
}
```

Alternatively you could create a map of what days of weeks are closer, e.g if you're after closest Monday to Wednesday, it would be faster to just find the previous Monday given that it's closer than the next Monday.

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers posted and I keep seeing solutions that could give me either the **next** instance of a day of the week or the **previous** instance **but not the closest**. To address this, I came up with this function:

```
function closestDate($day){

    $day = ucfirst($day);
    if(date('l', time()) == $day)
        return date("Y-m-d", time());
    else if(abs(time()-strtotime('next '.$day)) < abs(time()-strtotime('last '.$day)))
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next '.$day));
    else
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last '.$day));

}
```

Input: a day of the week ("sunday", "Monday", etc.)

Output: If I asked for the nearest "sunday" and today is:

1. "Sunday": I will get today's date
2. "Monday": I will get yesterday's date
3. "Saturday: I will get tomorrow's date

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is magical

```
echo date("d/m/y", strtotime("next sunday", strtotime("07.05.2010")  ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using only `strtotime()` and a little trickery.

```
function findNearest($day, $date)
{
    return strtotime("next $day", strtotime("$date - 4 days"));
}

echo date('d.m.Y', findNearest("Sunday", "07.05.2010")); // 09.05.2010
echo               findNearest("Sunday", "07.05.2010");  // 1273377600
echo date('d.m.Y', findNearest("Sunday", "09.05.2010")); // 09.05.2010
echo               findNearest("Sunday", "09.05.2010");  // 1273377600
echo date('d.m.Y', findNearest("Sunday", "05.05.2010")); // 02.05.2010
echo               findNearest("Sunday", "05.05.2010");  // 1272772800
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon library as well

```
$date = Carbon::create(2015, 7, 2); // 2015-07-02

// To get the first day of the week 
$monday = $date->startOfWeek(); // 2015-06-29

$mondayTwoWeeksLater = $date->addWeek(2); // 2015-07-13
```