# Find closest sunday to date?

Tags: php

I am trying to find the closest previous Sunday to a date (unless date is Sunday).

**So for example, if I have this array:**

```
$dates = array(
    "2014-03-02 10:15:10", // sun
    "2014-03-03 12:15:10", // mon
    "2014-03-04 13:15:10", // tue
    "2014-03-05 10:15:10", // wed
    "2014-03-06 14:15:10", // thu
    "2014-03-07 18:15:10", // fri
    "2014-03-08 14:15:10", // sat
    "2014-03-09 14:15:10"  // sun
);
```

**How can I efficiently output this:**

```
$dates = array(
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-02 00:00:00", // sun
    "2014-03-09 00:00:00"  // sun
);
```

Comment: The question has been closed, but I was working on my answer: http://pastie.org/8912529 . It's different than all others

Comment: I think there's an easier method: `$date = new DateTime($dateFromYourArray);` `$date->modify(0 - $date->format('w') . ' day');` `$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784507/870729):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday', strtotime($date)));
```

In your case:

```
$dates = array_map('find_sunday', $dates);

function find_sunday($date) {
    if (date('w', strtotime($date)) == 0) {
         return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
    }
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday', strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: thx...but doesnt work when the date being checked IS sunday.

Comment: thx... still doesnt work ;)

Comment: its outputting exactly what it output before